# GWT: How to apply a CSS3 gradient

Tags: gwt, css

I was tasked to build the front-end of a web application and what I'm trying to do is to apply a CSS3 gradient on a Button. I'm using Eclipse with the GWT Plugin and I'm viewing the UI in Google Chrome with the GWT plugin.

My problem is that GWT seems to remove whitespaces in between the parenthesis so that:

```
.gwt-Button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, white, #72C6E4 4%, #0C5FA5);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(white), to(#0C5FA5), color-stop(0.03, #72C6E4));
```

becomes:

```
.gwt-Button {
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,white,#72C6E44%,#0C5FA5);
    background:-webkit-gradient(linear,lefttop,lefbottom, from(white), to(#0C5FA5), color-stop(0.03, #72C6E4));
```

Which makes them invalid. Is there another way to go about this or maybe a way to prevent the whitespaces from being removed when application is compiled? Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

You have to use the literal() function.  I believe it may only work with styles used via aCssResource as its a GWT function.

```
background: -webkit-gradient(linear, literal("left top"),
            literal("left bottom"), from(white), to(#0C5FA5) );
```

I bugged this a while ago [here](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/issues/detail?id=5771&q=css%20literal&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Milestone%20Summary%20Stars) but haven't gotten any response from the GWT team, so please Star it if you think its a valid bug.

Also, as a side note, those styles won't work with older versions of ie, you need to add the filter property.  Here's an [example](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/cross-browser-css-gradient).

Comment: Maybe I'll do that. I'm pretty sure it's something to do with it inside a parenthesis because shorthands are being parsed properly. 

EDIT: 
It's for internal use only so it's fine to target gecko and webkit browsers only.

I went about the problem by adding the CSS file in the HTML file.